# Redis cache-miss behavior

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, redis

New to redis and it's full abilities. Currently I have a small web front-end that can determine if the item is in redis cache or not -- if it's not, it fetches the item from S3 and adds to redis cache.

**Is there a way I can have Redis actually perform an action (or run a script) on a cache-miss?** Ideally I remove this web front-end and have the client (which is actually a REST server) connect directly to redis to retrieve the data (and redis would load the missing data from S3 on a miss) ...

TIA

Comment: Redis can't do it on its own... what is your web front-end? 
You could use nginx instance with redis module and have it check for cached content in redis. If it's not there fetch it from S3 and save to redis.

Comment: The Lua scripting available inside Redis is limited to only operate on Redis data, not access the outside world. So you're going to have to wrap Redis in something else. Nginx is a natural match since it also uses Lua, but you could use any language that has Redis support, subject to your performance needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis doesn't provide that out of the box. However, it is open source so you could add your own logic to it if you really want... go http://github.com/antirez/redis, fork and start coding.

Comment: what happens if key has been moved out of redis by the eviction algorithm ?

Comment: @bruce_wayne I'm not sure I understand the question. Perhaps you should create a new question with all the details?